# Get Past data from Sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I insert a data point into a sqlite3 database on a nightly basis. Could anyone tell me how to obtain the data points for the past 30 days?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: What do you mean "data point"? Can you provide an example of how you're creating these "data points"?

Comment: data points are just test scores. I will be including the date field in the table and want to get the past data (ex: past 30 days data, past 90 days data). Also, I will be inserting only one data point for each test every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a very lightweight DB engine, so as far as I know, it doesn't store historical insert information. You have to have a date field in your table that gets set when you insert data.

One possible hack around this (if you're in a tight spot) is to use the auto-increment key/id field of your table to get the last 30 rows. This will only work if you haven't deleted any data since then, and have only been inserting exactly one row per day:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM table) - 30)
```

Comment: This assumes that there is exactly one record per day, which seems a very fragile assumption. Better would be to record a timestamp, and query "past 30 days" based on that timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the table has the timestamp of each data point.

```
CREATE TABLE smodgen (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    when DATETIME NOT NULL,
    sensor_value INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then you can use that timestamp to query the data points.

```
SELECT id, when, sensor_value
FROM smodgen
WHERE
    when >= DATETIME('now', '-30 days');
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I just needed this: time >= DATETIME('now', '-30 days'); (data from the past 30 days to 'now').